# Variable "name" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add a field name to my register page , i'm using fosuserbundle. But i got this error:

Variable "name" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 55

Thank you

config.yml

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
fos_user:
    db_driver:              orm
    firewall_name:          main
    user_class: FLY\UserBundle\Entity\User
    use_listener:           true
    #use_flash_notifications: true
    use_username_form_type: true
    model_manager_name:     null  # change it to the name of your entity/document manager if you don't want to use the default one.
    from_email:
        address:       xxxxxxx@hotmail.fr
        sender_name:    webmaster
    profile:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
    change_password:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_change_password
            name:               fos_user_change_password_form
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
    registration:
        confirmation:
            from_email: # Use this node only if you don't want the global email address for the confirmation email
                address:        xxxxxx@hotmail.fr
                sender_name:   Webmaster
            enabled:    true # change to true for required email confirmation
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
        form:
            type:               fos_user_registration
            name:               fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 86400
        email:
            from_email: # Use this node only if you don't want the global email address for the resetting email
                address:        ...
                sender_name:    ...
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Resetting:email.txt.twig
        form:
            type:               fos_user_resetting
            name:               fos_user_resetting_form
            validation_groups:  [ResetPassword, Default]
    service:
        mailer:                 fos_user.mailer.default
        email_canonicalizer:    fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        username_canonicalizer: fos_user.util.canonicalizer.default
        token_generator:        fos_user.util.token_generator.default
        user_manager:           fos_user.user_manager.default
    #group:
        #group_class:    ~ # Required when using groups
        #group_manager:  fos_user.group_manager.default
        #form:
            #type:               fos_user_group
            #name:               fos_user_group_form
            #validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
```

**register_content.html.twig**

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
  {% block header %}
  {% endblock header %}

{% block content %}


    <section id="headlogin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="btn pull-right">
                    <br/>
                    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}" class="btn btn-border-purple-light nl-btn">
                        {% trans %}Log in{% endtrans %}
                    </a></div></div>
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="leadlogin">AWESOME, CUSTOMIZABLE, FREE</h1>
                <p class="taglinelogin">PROGRESSUS: free business bootstrap template by Template</p>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 centeredlogin">
                    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <div class="panel panel-login">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
                                                    Hello {{ app.user.username }}


                                                    Logout

                                                {% else %}
                                                    {{ render(url('hwi_oauth_connect')) }}
                                                {% endif %}

                                                <button class="form-control btn btn-blue">
                                                    <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
                                                    {% trans %}Log in with facebook{% endtrans %}
                                                    <a href="{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', {'service': 'facebook' }) }}" alt="Sign in with Facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                {{ form_widget(name) }}
                                                <div style="margin-bottom:1px" class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                                    {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.username'|trans } }) }}
                                                    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
                                                </div></div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div style="margin-bottom: 1px" class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                                                    {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.email'|trans } }) }}
                                                    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                                                </div></div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div style="margin-bottom: 1px" class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                                    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.password'|trans } }) }}
                                                    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}


                                                    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.password_confirmation'|trans } }) }}
                                                    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                                                    {{ form_rest(form) }}
                                                </div></div>
                                            {{ form_rest(form) }}
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                        <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" class="form-control btn btn-whitered">
                                                            <i class="icon ion-log-in"></i>
                                                            {{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        {% render(controller('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect')) %}
        </div>
    </section>

{% endblock content %}
{% block foot_script %}
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId      : '708572945914167',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                //channelUrl : '//yourdomain.com/channel.html',      // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function fb_login() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    alert('Already connected, redirect to login page to create token.');
                    document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                } else {
                    // not_authorized
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                        } else {
                            alert('Cancelled.');
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'email'});
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <h1 class="title">Hello {{ name }}!</h1>

    <a href="{{ path('_demo_secured_hello_admin', { 'name': name }) }}">Hello resource secured for <strong>admin</strong> only.</a>

    <p>
        <a href="#" onclick="fb_login();">Facebook Connect Button (Dialog)</a>
    </p>

    {# Bonus: Show all available login link in HWIOAuthBundle #}
    {% render(controller('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect')) %}
{% endblock foot_script %}

{% block footer %} {% endblock footer %}
```

services.yml

```
**parameters:
    hwi_oauth.user.provider.class: FLY\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
services:
    hwi_oauth.user.provider:
        class: hwi_oauth.user.provider.class
        #this is the place where the properties are passed to the UserProvider - see config.yml
        arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebook_id,}]
    boutique_user.registration.form.type:
        class: FLY\Form\MyRegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
             - { name: form.type, alias: boutique_user.registration.form.type: }**
```

**MyRegistrationFormType.php**

```
<?php
namespace FLY\UserBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class MyRegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm(builder,$options);
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'boutique_user_registration';
    }}
```

**RegistrationForm.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $class;
    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }
    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

FOSUserProvider.php

```
**<?php
/*
 * This file is part of the HWIOAuthBundle package.
 *
 * (c) Hardware.Info <opensource@hardware.info>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace FLY\Bundle\UserBundle\Security\Core\User;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
            $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }
        //we connect current user
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        //when the user is registrating
        if (null === $user) {
            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
            $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
            $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
            // create new user here
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->$setter_id($username);
            $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
            //I have set all requested data with the user's username
            //modify here with relevant data
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($username);
            $user->setPassword($username);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            return $user;
        }
        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';
        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());
        return $user;
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form_widget(**form**.name) }}
```